# Estimate for absolute valuue

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I need some help to prove the following inequality: let $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $$|x|\le\frac12+\frac {x^2}2.$$

Answer (score 3):

$y^2\geq 0$

(Consider $y=1\pm x$.)

Comment: Or, maybe even simpler: $y=|x|-1$.

Answer (score 3):

You may assume that $x\ge 0$. Then the inequality becomes
$$
x\le {1\over2}+{x^2\over 2};
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
2x\le 1+x^2,
$$
or
$$
x^2-2x+1\ge 0.
$$
Now note that $x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2$.

Comment: The phrase "is equivalent to" reminds me of a time when I was explaining to a class how to prove a trigonometric identity.  When I said something is equivalent to something else, someone asked: "Does equivalent to mean 'equal to'?".  People are full of surprises.  (Just in case anyone is unsure: _No_.  It does _not_ mean "equal to".)

Comment: @MichaelHardy I wish I had a nickel for every time I had to say or write "equations (or inequalities) are not *equal* to each other".